# Expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'CFXMLTreeRef' Error when importing CoreServices?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS development so I am not sure why I would get a compilation error here. Hopefully someone can explain. When I import CoreServices I get the following error when I attempt to compile.

> Expected declaration specifiers or
>   '...' before 'CFXMLTreeRef'

Can someone help?

```
#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```

The debugger points to this line in WSMethodInvocation.h:

```
typedef CALLBACK_API( CFTypeRef , WSMethodInvocationDeserializationProcPtr )(WSMethodInvocationRef invocation, CFXMLTreeRef msgRoot, CFXMLTreeRef deserializeRoot, void *info);
```

I am not using any function from this file.. I am just importing CoreServices and the error pops up. I am attempting to use:

> CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost

Comment: Post the lines of the code which caused the error themselves! Otherwise, how could we know???

Comment: I updated my post. The import is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Mmm ... that's strange. Do you import anything before CoreServices? What's the compiler? In my machine, an almost empty line with just `#import <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>` compiled without problems.

Comment: @Yuji did you try this in an iPhone SDK project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the CoreServices are **not** available on iOS. Instead, use

```
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
```

You might want to add the framework to the list of "linked frameworks" in the XCode side panel, too.

Comment: I thought it had to be a platform issue. These frameworks are all very new to me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Yuji: Please have a look at my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116050/why-do-i-get-a-compilation-error-in-coreservices-wsmethodinvocation-h