# Compilation error in MacOSX CoreServices on iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode4

This is probably some silly thing I did wrong in using frameworks, but I spent some hours now, and hope someone can help!

My compilation error:

`Expected * before *` and `error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'CFXMLTreeRef'` in `WSMethodInvocation.h` and `WSProtocolHandler.h`. Both in `/Developer/SDKs/**MacOSX10.6.sdk**/System/Library/Frameworks/**CoreServices**.framework´

They list files where `UIKit` and `Foundation` are included. I have included these framework, but not the CoreServices framework.

[image: Framworks included in my project]

What I've tried:

- I **removed frameworks from my project folder** that was accidentally copied there (I had checked "Copy resources" while adding them.)
- I have made sure that the **Framework Search Paths** is empty. (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008800/ios-sdk-broken-ever-after-reinstall-uikit-and-foundation-frameworks-not-found))
- I chose **Show in finder** on all frameworks in the project, and they are all located under `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library`.
- In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137816/expected-declaration-specifiers-or-before-cfxmltreeref-error-when-import) it says Most of the **CoreServices** are not available on iOS. Instead, use `#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>`, so I tried that, desperately, with no luck. But again why do I even get an error in one of the **MacOSX CoreServices** classes?

It all worked fine before I started adding and moving projects and frameworks. I have tried to restore everything to how it was before, when it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved all my code to a new project. Works fine, using the same frameworks.

If anyone have an idea of what broke, that is still welcome. :)